# XSL Duplicate a Parent node to be its own Parent node

Tags: xslt

I have a complicated requirement where in I need to duplicate the Parent node and make it its own Parent node. It will now become a child node and will have escaped characters. Please see sample below:

Sample:

```
<Messages>
<Parameters>
      <Field1>1</Field1>
      <Field2>2</Field2>
</Parameters>
<Parameters>
      <Field3>3</Field3>
      <Field4>4</Field4>
</Parameters>
</Messages>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Messages>
<Parameters>
&lt;Parameters&gt;
&lt;Field1&gt;1&lt;/Field1&gt;
&lt;Field2&gt;2&lt;/Field2&gt;
&lt;/Parameters&gt;
</Parameters>
<Parameters>
&lt;Parameters&gt;
&lt;Field3&gt;3&lt;/Field3&gt;
&lt;Field4&gt;4&lt;/Field4&gt;
&lt;/Parameters&gt;
</Parameters>
</Messages>
```

Is this possible? I actually have the XSL code for escaping characters thanks to another stackoverflow forum answer. I'm not sure though how to create the parent node.

Thanks Guys!
Regards,
XSL Newbie

My code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ns0:Messages>
    </xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#32;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">=&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ns0:Messages">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I added them in my original post. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check whether your XSLT processor supports an extension function to serialize a tree nodes to XML as that usually does a better job then a few XSLT templates thrown together. For instance with an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9.6 you can simply use the `serialize` function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

    <xsl:variable name="ser-params">
        <output:serialization-parameters
               xmlns:output="http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization">
          <output:method value="xml"/>
          <output:version value="1.0"/>
          <output:indent value="yes"/>
          <output:omit-xml-declaration value="yes"/>
        </output:serialization-parameters>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parameters">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="serialize(., $ser-params/*)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you want to use your approach then use modes e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Parameters">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="serialize"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then your templates to output the serialized markup need to define and use the mode e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="serialize"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*" mode="serialize">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">&#32;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">=&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;quot;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

More corrections might be needed but you have used namespaces in your stylesheet without showing any in your sample XML, so it is not possible to tell where the corrections are needed.